# Java Web Service client error

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, web-services

I was creating a Java web service server, using eclipse IDE. that server is the following.

Note: I am working in UBUNTU

```
package com.tesis.service;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException;

import com.mathworks.engine.*;

/**
 * @author root
 *
 */
public class CNNPredict 
{
    public String cNNPredict(int[] Image, int Height, int Width) throws Exception
    {
        String FilePath =   "/home/user/Documents/MATLAB/Project";
        char[] CharFilePath = FilePath.toCharArray();
        MatlabEngine eng = MatlabEngine.startMatlab();
        eng.feval("cd", CharFilePath);
        String result = eng.feval("CNNPredict",Image,Height,Width);
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using MATLAB engine. 
[Matlab engine documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/execute-matlab-functions-from-java.html). I checked that cNNPredict method is working properly by copying it into a new Java project and It worked perfectly.
I added the .jar files required to run java engine to the Dynamic web project where the web service is located.

Apparently this web service runs without problems [Web Service working in local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7u1G.png)
If I click on "CnnPredict" link I get the wsdl direction of the class , this direction is what I use to link the client with the server.

this is the client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CNNPredictExceptionException
{
    CNNPredictStub stub = new CNNPredictStub();
    CNNPredict cnn = new CNNPredict();
    BufferedImage img = null;
    System.out.println("Reading image ...");
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/riosgamarra/Documents/MATLAB/TesisGamarrarios/101_ObjectCategories/laptop/image_0009.jpg"));
    int[] UnrolledImage = convertToGray(img);
    cnn.setImage(UnrolledImage);
    cnn.setWidth(img.getWidth());
    cnn.setHeight(img.getHeight());
    System.out.println(stub.cNNPredict(cnn).get_return());

}
```

It has no errors, but when I run it this error message shows up:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: <faultstring>com/mathworks/engine/MatlabEngine</faultstring>
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:513)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:368)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:414)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
    at com.tesis.service.CNNPredictStub.cNNPredict(CNNPredictStub.java:197)
    at com.tesis.client.CallWS.main(CallWS.java:40)
```

what I am missing ? do I need to add any special permissions to the server project ? What Am I missing ?

Note: I run the client clicking  on the class and selecting Run as > Java application.

Comment: as a side note. Are you coding as root? Not good :-}

Comment: Could you be more specific  please, Don´t know what do you mean with "coding as root". Thanks

Comment: /**
 * @author root
 *
 */ It is in the source you posted

Comment: Thanks, now I see it, But could you tell me why this situation is generating the error in the code or if I need to add some complements in the project??

Comment: I will post my comments for convenience of space

Answer (score 0):

```
 at com.tesis.service.CNNPredictStub.cNNPredict(CNNPredictStub.java:197)
```

is where the exception is but

```
public class CNNPredict 
{
    public String cNNPredict(int[] Image, int Height, int Width) throws Exception
    {
        String FilePath =   "/home/user/Documents/MATLAB/Project";
        char[] CharFilePath = FilePath.toCharArray();
        MatlabEngine eng = MatlabEngine.startMatlab();
        eng.feval("cd", CharFilePath);
        String result = eng.feval("CNNPredict",Image,Height,Width);
        return result;
    }
}
```

is not the stub. First we need to the right code to look at. The matlab api is straight forward. My guess is that the stub is making the wrong call